# Prove that the eigenvalues of a random matrix of this form, are invariant regardless of the value of the exponent $s$.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, random-matrices, harmonic-numbers

Consider the sequence:

$$\frac{\sum _{k=1}^1 \frac{1^s}{k^s}}{1^s},\frac{\sum _{k=1}^2 \frac{2^s}{k^s}}{2^s},\frac{\sum _{k=1}^3 \frac{3^s}{k^s}}{3^s},...,\frac{\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{n^s}{k^s}}{n^s} \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(1)$$

This of course simplifies to the Harmonic numbers:

$$\sum _{k=1}^1 \frac{1}{k^s},\sum _{k=1}^2 \frac{1}{k^s},\sum _{k=1}^3 \frac{1}{k^s},...,\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^s}$$

Some Mathematica code to try it out:

```
s = 3;
nn = 12;
a = Table[Sum[(n^s/k^s), {k, 1, n}]/n^s, {n, 1, nn}]
HarmonicNumber[Range[nn], s]
```

But focus on the summand in the numerator in sequence $(1)$ for a moment.

Let $A$ be a matrix with arbitrary (random) entries:

$$A=\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
 a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,5} & ... & a_{1,k} \\
 a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & a_{2,3} & a_{2,4} & a_{2,5} & ... & a_{2,k} \\
 a_{3,1} & a_{3,2} & a_{3,3} & a_{3,4} & a_{3,5} & ... & a_{3,k} \\
 a_{4,1} & a_{4,2} & a_{4,3} & a_{4,4} & a_{4,5} & ... & a_{4,k} \\
 a_{5,1} & a_{5,2} & a_{5,3} & a_{5,4} & a_{5,5} & ... & a_{5,k} \\
 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
 a_{n,1} & a_{n,2} & a_{n,3} & a_{n,4} & a_{n,5} & ... & a_{n,k} 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Multiply elementwise the arbitrary matrix $A$ with the numerator of the summand in $(1)$, so that you get:

$$A_{\text{Harmonic}}=\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
 \frac{1^s}{1^s}a_{1,1} & \frac{1^s}{2^s}a_{1,2} & \frac{1^s}{3^s}a_{1,3} & \frac{1^s}{4^s}a_{1,4} & \frac{1^s}{5^s}a_{1,5} & ... & \frac{1^s}{k^s}a_{1,k} \\
 \frac{2^s}{1^s}a_{2,1} & \frac{2^s}{2^s}a_{2,2} & \frac{2^s}{3^s}a_{2,3} & \frac{2^s}{4^s}a_{2,4} & \frac{2^s}{5^s}a_{2,5} & ... & \frac{2^s}{k^s}a_{2,k} \\
 \frac{3^s}{1^s}a_{3,1} & \frac{3^s}{2^s}a_{3,2} & \frac{3^s}{3^s}a_{3,3} & \frac{3^s}{4^s}a_{3,4} & \frac{3^s}{5^s}a_{3,5} & ... & \frac{3^s}{k^s}a_{3,k} \\
 \frac{4^s}{1^s}a_{4,1} & \frac{4^s}{2^s}a_{4,2} & \frac{4^s}{3^s}a_{4,3} & \frac{4^s}{4^s}a_{4,4} & \frac{4^s}{5^s}a_{4,5} & ... & \frac{4^s}{k^s}a_{4,k} \\
 \frac{5^s}{1^s}a_{5,1} & \frac{5^s}{2^s}a_{5,2} & \frac{5^s}{3^s}a_{5,3} & \frac{5^s}{4^s}a_{5,4} & \frac{5^s}{5^s}a_{5,5} & ... & \frac{5^s}{k^s}a_{5,k} \\
 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
 \frac{n^s}{1^s}a_{n,1} & \frac{n^s}{2^s}a_{n,2} & \frac{n^s}{3^s}a_{n,3} & \frac{n^s}{4^s}a_{n,4} & \frac{n^s}{5^s}a_{n,5} & ... & \frac{n^s}{k^s}a_{n,k} 
\end{array}
\right)$$

> Prove or disprove that the eigenvalues of $A_{\text{Harmonic}}$ are the same regardless of the value of the exponent $s$.

In the program below I try to demonstrate that this is the case. Only problem is that Mathematica does not know how to sort complex numbers in a consistent order and therefore it sometimes gives non zero differences. So the program only demonstrates the weaker statement that the sum of the differences of the eigenvalues is zero.

The sum of the differences of the eigenvalues of two different matrices:

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{n=m} \lambda(1)_n-\lambda(2)_n = 0$$

is zero. But as I said, I am asking to prove that the eigenvalues actually are equal all the time.

Mathematica:

```
Clear[t, nn, n, k];
nn = 12
A = Table[
   Table[RandomReal[{-10, 10}] + RandomReal[{-10, 10}]*I, {k, 1, 
     nn}], {n, 1, nn}];
aa = Chop[Table[s = RandomReal[{-10, 10}] + RandomReal[{-10, 10}]*I;
   a = Table[Table[A[[n, k]]*(n^s/k^s), {k, 1, nn}], {n, 1, nn}];
   N[Eigenvalues[a]], {nn, 1, 7}]]
bb = Chop[Table[s = RandomReal[{-10, 10}] + RandomReal[{-10, 10}]*I;
   b = Table[Table[A[[n, k]]*(n^s/k^s), {k, 1, nn}], {n, 1, nn}];
   N[Eigenvalues[b]], {nn, 1, 7}]]
Print["Eigenvalues of the matrices are equal:"]
Chop[aa - bb]
Print["The sum of the differences of the eigenvalues is zero:"]
Chop[Table[Total[(aa - bb)[[m]]], {m, 1, Length[aa - bb]}]]
```

Comment: Why don't you look at $A = 1_{n\times k}$ first and explicitly compute all the eigenvalues for different $s$.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try that. But I don't know where it will lead me.

Comment: It's at least worth a try to check if your conjecture _could_ be valid or if you have an explicit counter-example.

Comment: I see. These are the eigenvalues that I got from the all ones matrix:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 \{1.\} \\
 \{2.,0\} \\
 \{3.,0,0\} \\
 \{4.,0,0,0\} \\
 \{5.,0,0,0,0\} \\
 \{6.,0,0,0,0,0\} \\
 \{7.,0,0,0,0,0,0\}
\end{array}
\right)$$ They too are invariant.

Comment: So it worked for all $s$? You should get eigenvalues of
$$1_{n\times n} \odot H_s$$
Where $(H_s)_{ij} = \frac{i^s}{j^s}$ and $\odot$ is the Hadamard product.

Comment: It appears to work for random $s$. Is a Hadamard product the same as the element wise product somehow?

Comment: Yes, the Hadamard product _is_ the element-wise matrix product (MATLAB `.*`)

Comment: Do you mean $A$ is fixed and only $s$ is changed?

Comment: Yes that is a better way to say it. I mean given a matrix $A$, change $s$ and calculate the eigenvalues and compare.

Comment: I think $n = k$ in your matrix, is that right?

Comment: No I don't understand how you mean. $(n/k)^s$ where $n=1,2,3,...N$ and $k=1,2,3,...K$

Comment: But if you mean "Is it a square matrix?", then the answer is yes.